# How can I save a web page as single page PDF?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

Web pages can be very long. When I save it as PDF, chrome splits it to multiple pages. Is there a way to create a single page PDF with custom page width/length?

I need it to be a PDF in order to insert as attachment in wiki pages I’m maintaining.

Comment: Is there a reason you need it to be PDF? every browser can also save as compact web page: MHT which stores all files and text and graphics etc inside the file. Opening the MHT file will open it in the browser and you'll see exactly what you saw before the export, except this time offline.

Comment: I'm appalled that there's no plugin to save an auto-sized PDF page of w hole web page (with similar browser width, for example).  WHo prints stuff physically anyway?

Comment: @LPChip The thing is: it does not preserve _dynamic_ contents very well, resulting in broken saved webpages.

Answer (score 0):

Print the page and select "Adobe PDF" as the printer. This will allow you print the page content in a readable format. You can also use the "Selection only" box to "print" only the content you want (see first screenshot below).

To set a custom page size, click "Print using system dialogue," select "Adobe PDF," and click "Preferences." In the preferences window, go to the "Paper/Quality" tab, and click "Advanced." In the advanced dialogue, open the "Paper Size" drop-down menu and select either a preset or custom page size (see second screenshot below).

[image]
[image]

Comment: It breaks a long page into several pages in the pdf

Comment: I've added instructions for using custom page sizes to my original answer. Can you confirm that you see "Adobe PDF" as an available printer? The Print to PDF plugin that I am using was included with Acrobat XI Pro so you may not see these same exact options.

Comment: Another option would be changing the view settings in Acrobat (or whichever PDF viewer you are using) to eliminate the gaps between the pages. In Reader or Acrobat XI, you'd go to View  -> Page Display -> and uncheck "Show gaps between pages"

Comment: What page size do you choose for "just include everything on this whole page"? (i think that was the question, right?)